# Do we need the [moderation-strike] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I've seen the [moderation-strike](/questions/tagged/moderation-strike) tag popping up a few times this past month. I'm wondering, do we really *need* it?
It doesn't seem to have much long-term utility, though I may turn out to be wrong on that. Should we be editing it out?

I ask because of a [pending suggested-edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/86724) on the wiki.

(Sorry if we aren't supposed to make meta-posts about specific tags.)

Comment: Well, the strike has been on for a month and half now, not sure when 'long-term' kicks in :(

Comment: Wow, has it really been that long?

Comment: Where else would one meta posts about meta tags or if they are metatags ?

Comment: What if we use one tag for all strikes, past, present and future? Then time tha is taking the current strike and the steikes happening in other places, I. E.  Reddit, make it look that strikes will be occurring more and more frequently

Comment: @Wicket there wasn't a strike in the past. Back in 2019 many mods retired or stepped down as mods, which is different.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337237/how-can-we-improve-the-inconsistent-tagging-of-the-questions-relating-to-the-rec. (TL;DR: it didn't result in new tags)

Comment: Name it [tag:moderation-strike-2023], just in case there is another one… also don’t forget to tag staff posts with it.

Comment: @pppery Start was Monday June 5th 2023.

Comment: In addition to Meta Stack Exchange, Meta Stack Overflow has a tag called [moderation-strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderation-strike), too. It seems that there aren't other sites with this tag at the moment: https://stackexchange.com/filters/447605/moderation-strike

Comment: ... except for Academia main, which has a tag for this but they call it just "moderation" instead.

Comment: The `moderation-strike` tag doesn't even include https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/ or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811, which makes it seem not very useful.

Comment: @jamesdlin They do now, probably as a result of you pointing that out. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 42):

## Yes

All that matters here is that there are enough questions about the moderation strike to warrant a tag, which there seem to be. Tags don't need "long-term utility", or else we wouldn't have [winter-bash-2020](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2020), for instance.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, but it may be more practical to use words other than "strike".

Stack Exchange doesn't use the word "strike" (probably for legal reasons).
So Stack Exchange's own posts will never be tagged with "moderation-strike".
As a result, this tag becomes less useful. If there is a compromise in the choice of words to use, I think it is good to go with it.

Comment: Agreed, if the purpose is to tag staff posts with it as well, the name may have to change. Otherwise it's fine imo and its existence is warranted

Answer (score -14):

## **No**

Unless this is a feature provided by the site, I don't see why this should be present. Will the site provide a *strike* feature for whoever wants to? Will it provide moderators to limit their access to mod tools and privileged information for the duration they want to strike? How about general users? And everyone seems to have their own definition of what the strike means anyway. What does any strike entail actually? Just shouting out "I'm on strike" on the site at every chance you get, to anyone who does or doesn't want to know? Or is it only about curation, such as not up/down voting, not doing user level review/moderation, not doing mod level moderation, not visiting/interacting with the site at all, etc? In this case *all* of these operations are voluntary, and has been so regardless of any kind of strike. What about the opposite? What if someone is against the strike, or against some people's notion that whole "community" is on strike just because they are? What if someone is neutral? Do they get their own tags?

Having a separate tag for this does not seem necessary.

Comment: It is a meaningful event in the history of Stack Exchange. It affects management, it's mentioned by the CEO himself in interviews, etc.

Comment: "meaningful" is subjective. There have been lots of other meaningful events in the history of the site, I don't think each one had their own tag. Also doesn't really address any points I raised in my post. Some users volunteering to not do certain actions on the site that are voluntary to begin with, is not a significant event imho

Comment: There are several "meta" tags that do not correspond to features. For example, there is no announcement feature yet there is an announcement tag.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of questions about the strike. If you wanted to understand it better, you could post a question about them, and use a "strike" tag, should it be created - if you wanted to understand it better.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi are you really comparing something generic like "announcement" to some online drama that few people think should be considered significant? Just because some things that aren't exactly "features" have a tag, doesn't mean every non-feature needs their own tag. Have a generic "drama" tag instead then, so that it can apply to things other than strikes

Comment: @JonathanZ I don't see where you see I "seem to be having" questions about the strike , except for adding the piece of snark at the end of your comment. I don't have any questions about it (people who want to post they are "on strike", and post links to other posts about strike at every chance they get keep trying to make sure of that). I do have differing opinion on it, which it seems you aren't allowed to post without the risk of getting downvoted or being accused as a troublemaker

Comment: I just noticed the huge number of question marks in your answer, and very small number of straight-out statements. But if you are bothered by the idea of people who disagree with you downvoting your answer (which is how downvotes work on Meta), then I can understand why you would be hesitant to make statements.

Comment: @JonathanZ look closely and you'll see non of those are about "understanding" the strike if thats what you are thinking. And you may be taking just this one post at its face value, but the sentiment i expressed here is based on my experience on this site, others metas and other SE sites, and the general attitudes i have seen there. If i was bothered by the downvotes i wouldnt post this because i know from the general attitude in SE sites that the strike supporting mob is going to come and dv any opinion like this.

Comment: And look at the first word in this answer. **NO** by itself is a complete statement as an answer to the OP

Comment: @user13267 Yes I was, since „feature-ness“ seems to be the only concrete statement in this answer. Feel free to edit in whatever that point about drama is supposed to say (I am guessing that it is a temporary event; but there too are tags for such things, as the other answer already pointed out).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi read it again and find out that „feature-ness“ isn't the only concrete statement here. One could argue those who want to oppose the strike should also get their own tag for fairness. Again every temporary event does not need a tag and if some have been given in the past, its possible they weren't really necessary either. That doesn't mean every other temporary event needs one. And instead of this strike (and each and every other strike ) getting their own tag, maybe everything should get a drama tag so that non-strike drama can also be included. That's all I said...

Comment: ...You're the one who seems to believe this merits its own tag. There's no point to be made here and it's just a suggestion to those who think a tag for this is necessary. I don't see what you want me to "feel free to add". I know I am already free to add whatever I want in my own post.

Comment: @user13267 Honestly, I’ve tried hard to make sense of the (rhetorical?) questions in the answer but I am really not sure whether they are supposed to imply something about the tag or comment on the strike or something else. They may be statements but they are definitely not concrete. It seems like you have some arguments, as evidenced by some of your comments, but for some reason your answers seems to prefer… drama. That is of course your decision, but personally I find it a loss to have a good opposition wasted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm sure you are also only seeing the side you want to support ("have a good opposition wasted"). Any opposition might have been wasted on you. Otherwise you would know that the tag itself is a comment on the strike, a sort of "verification" for whatever it's worth, for those who want to support (or show their support/solidarity regardless of whether others want to know about it or not). You don't see concrete statements, that's on you. You might even be right, but my answer is what it its, which is bold **No** as stated, as this is not as important or unique an event as some...

Comment: ...people want to make it seem to be. People not doing stuff on the site that is voluntary to begin with does not need to have it's own tag. You don't want to moderate? Don't do it. You don't need to show off to everyone you're on strike to not moderate here.

Comment: The existence of a tag doesn't "verify" or "validate" anything else than the fact that some posts are topically related and that some users want to be able to filter or group on that criterion, perhaps to _exclude_ this topic if they don't want to read about it. I hate the monstrous word "folksonomy" itself, but you might want to google it for more information.

Comment: @tripleee I think in the case of this strike I think this general logic does not really apply. I have also suggested the more appropriate drama tag if people really need to have a tag for this.

Comment: I see you have, but that's way too broad. It's like having an "input" tag on Stack Overflow. I might well be tired of the moderation strike, but still be interested in reading about the CEO making ridiculous publicity statements, for example.

Comment: @tripleee something like CEO statement will probably come as company announcement in which case they wouldn't use any kind of strike tag at all (and users shouldn't be changing company posts based on what they think is correct anyway). As for users wanting to create their own strike tag for their use, it's already in my answer that I don't think its really necessary